# Building an entity-based sentiment analyzer

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I am currently working on building an entity-based sentiment analyzer, which when given a piece of text will detect the entities and give the sentiment score for each entity. For example, consider the following text

```
ICICI bank reported losses in the first quarter of FY 2022. Reliance on the other hand remains in an upward market performance.
```

So, in this case I will want to detect the two entities- `ICICI Bank and Reliance`, and give the sentiment scores for each. In this case, ICICI will have a negative sentiment score and Reliance will have a positive sentiment score.
I have built a custom entity recogniser using spacy and I am adding more data and improving the model to identify entities. I would like to understand how to go about building a sentiment analyzer tool. What kind of mapping will i need for entity to sentiment?I would really appreciate any inputs, resources to read up on the same. Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of tutorials if you search for "spacy sentiment", so this question feels a bit vague/general. After you've worked through the tutorials you should be able to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @DarrenCook So referring to the example mentioned above, My final model actually needs to compute the sentiment of the full text for each entity. The input will be news articles so the model will have to determine whether the news is positive or negative for ICICI bank and Reliance.